# HTML: готовый список шрифтов

Tags: html

Есть ли готовый список шрифтов для html страницы, что бы можно было подключить в несколько строчек кода? Под список шрифтов я имею ввиду выпадающий список как MS Word например.

Comment: Посмотрите это https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/

Comment: @AntonKucenko, примерно то что и хотел, спасибо большое)